# Subscriber function never called

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-meteor

I'm trying to query the server for a string token, which the client component will then use. The meteor method call on the client expects an asynchronous result, and returns an Observable. Once the method completes, it calls next on the Observable. The component subscribes to the Observable.

However, when the code runs, there's a problem. In the debugger, the Observable doesn't have any subscribers. So the Subscriber callback is not invoked when next() is called.

I'm unclear what's wrong, and would appreciate another set of experienced eyes.

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: "test",
  template: ``
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  myToken: Observable<string>;
  private tokenSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private theService: SomeService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myToken = this.theService.createToken(); 
    this.tokenSubscription = this.myToken.subscribe((token: string) => {
        this.doSomething(token);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.tokenSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  doSomething(token: string) {
//    ...
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class SomeService {

  createToken(): Observable<string> {
      let subject: Subject<string> = Subject.create();
      Meteor.call("serverOnly.createToken", (err, result: {"data": string}) => {
          if (err) {
              throw new Meteor.Error("createToken", err);
          } else {
              subject.next(result.data);
          }
      });

      return subject.asObservable();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to catch the error in the subscription like so

```
this.tokenSubscription = this.myToken.subscribe((token: string) => {
    this.doSomething(token);
}, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

--**UPDATE**--

Use `ReplaySubject` instead of `Subject`. As `Subject` will only be able to push the data to past subscribers, i.e., in your case `subject.next()` is being called before the subscription which will not push the value to the stream as there are no subscribers at the moment.

```
let subject: ReplaySubject<string> = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);
```

Here **1** is the buffer value which says how many previous values emitted by calling .next on it should be sent to the future subscribers (in this case it is 1 previous value)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but err (and completion) callbacks are never called, since for some reason the subscription has no subscribers